# Не могу понять как взять переменную из класса не указывая ее конкретно

Tags: c#, .net, условия

Проблема состоит в том, что я создал класс, в котором перечисляются имена людей, и хочу чтобы при вводе слова, совпадающего с созданным именем пользователь получал характеристики конкретного объекта(специально для этого в классе "Friend" создал метод. У меня возникают сложности с тем, как сделать проверку того, совпадает ли введенная пользователем строка с существующем именем(не вписывая каждое имя отдельно и вручную через if).
Вот весь код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace classes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi, enter your friend name: ");
            string checkname = Console.ReadLine();

            Friend Mark = new Friend();
            Mark.name = "Mark";
            Mark.age = 52;
            Mark.weight = 53.5f;

            Friend John = new Friend();
            John.name = "John";
            John.age = 17;
            John.weight = 60;

            Friend Piter = new Friend();
            Piter.name = "Piter";
            Piter.age = 29;
            Piter.weight = 63;

            Friend Virginia = new Friend();
            Virginia.name = "Virginia";
            Virginia.age = 17;
            Virgignia.weight = 47.5f;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Friend
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        public float weight;

        public void PrintAll()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
            Console.WriteLine("Weight:" + weight);
        }
    }
}
```

Я попробовал сделать что-то вроде этого, но, сами понимаете, ничего не получилось

```
            Console.WriteLine("Hi, enter your friend name: ");
            string checkname = Console.ReadLine();

            if (checkname == Friend.name() )
                Friend.name().PrintAll();
```

Да, извиняюсь, за, возможно, глупый вопрос, но я ничего не нашел в интернете по решению моей проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть класс

```
class Friend
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public float weight;

    public void PrintAll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
        Console.WriteLine("Weight:" + weight);
    }
}
```

То вы можете насоздовать друузей и положить из в список

```
Friend Mark = new Friend();
Mark.name = "Mark";
Mark.age = 52;
Mark.weight = 53.5f;

Friend John = new Friend();
John.name = "John";
John.age = 17;
John.weight = 60;

Friend Piter = new Friend();
Piter.name = "Piter";
Piter.age = 29;
Piter.weight = 63;

Friend Virginia = new Friend();
Virginia.name = "Virginia";
Virginia.age = 17;
Virginia.weight = 47.5f;

var list = new List<Friend>();
list.Add(Mark);
list.Add(John);
list.Add(Piter);
list.Add(Virginia);
```

Тогда поиск будет элементарным

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi, enter your friend name: ");
string checkname = Console.ReadLine();
var friend = list.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.name == checkname);
if (friend!=null) friend.PrintAll();
    else Console.WriteLine("I dont know you!");
Console.ReadKey();
```